# How to change text place

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

View of my container at the moment: [image]

I try to set like this:

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-3" text-center> 
<div class="row">
    <h2><center>FAQ</center></h2>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-5" style="margin-left:50px; margin-right=-50px;">
        <p><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit?</strong></p>
        <p style="margin-bottom:30px;">Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus accumsan et viverra justo commodo. Proin sodales pulvinar tempor.</p>
        <p><strong>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus?</strong></p>
        <p style="margin-bottom:30px;">Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus accumsan et viverra justo commodo. Proin sodales pulvinar tempor.</p>
        <p><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit?</strong></p>
        <p style="margin-bottom:30px;">Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus accumsan et viverra justo commodo. Proin sodales pulvinar tempor.</p>
        <p><strong>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus?</strong></p>
        <p style="margin-bottom:50px;">Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus accumsan et viverra justo commodo. Proin sodales pulvinar tempor.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <p><strong>Got more questions? write to us:</strong></p>
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4  col-sm-4">
            <button style="width:100%" type="submit" class="btn-outlined btn-black btn-lg btn-group">ASK QUESTION</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't how can I center text and after that align to left. When I add margins, everything is wrong. Should I use col-xs-* & text-center or something other?

Answer (score 1):

If you want some column to be centered you should try to use col-[mediabreakpoint]-offsett-[number].
I assume, that you are using Bootstrap 3.x, since the syntax for BS 4 is different.
In your case you should try doing it like this:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-lg-4  col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
        <button style="width:100%" type="submit" class="btn-outlined btn-black btn-lg btn-group">ASK QUESTION</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
```

For further information take a look to these [examples](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)

For displaying the the question on the right place you should nest in within a 'column' div.

Answer (score 0):

Your question text is in the same row as the main text.

Put it in another row (which you tried to do but missed it by wrong div nesting) or put it in the same div as your main text div (or column).

The div that has the class row and clearfix should be moved out of its current parent

Answer (score -1):

Given the structure of your html, the easiest would be the following ... basically just adding text-align: center;  for the whole container and then overriding the aligning for the "content" to left

```css
#container{
    width: 75%;
  
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#content{
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <p id="title">FAQ</p>
    <div id="content">
        All your content here
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>If you got questions, write to us</p>
        <input type="text" value=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a fine solution, however, as the tags show, the OP is using Bootstrap. Instead of asking him to create new rules in CSS, I suggest that we tell him how to use the ones already existent in the library he has chosen.

Comment: I am not asking to create new rules. I am providing an example. If you take a minute next time (before down marking) you will see that I tend not to give answers but pointing in the direction.

Comment: As you can see in the homepage of Stackoverflow, this is a Question and answer site, not a Question and "pointing in the direction" site. If you think I am wrong, you can ask in meta.

Comment: Well, then you should use your time more wisely, as I am not the only one who "points" people in right direction, and you will be very busy telling all the others what you just told me.  You can also ask in meta!